# PHPExcel chunkReadFilter memory fails even chunksize equal 1 row

Tags: php, memory, phpexcel, xlsx

I'm trying to read not so large XLSX file (2Mb, 30000 rows, 17 cols)
I'm using chunk reader as mentioned in documentation

```
...
require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/PHPExcel/IOFactory.php';
PHPExcel_Settings::setZipClass(PHPExcel_Settings::PCLZIP);
$filename = TMP . 'app.xlsx';
$sheetname = 'test_sheet'; 

require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/PHPExcel/Filter.php'; // simple chunkReadFilter class
$chunkFilter = new chunkReadFilter();
$chunkSize = 1;
$startRow = 10;

$objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader("Excel2007");
$objReader->setReadDataOnly(true);
$chunkFilter->setRows($startRow, $chunkSize); 
$objReader->setReadFilter($chunkFilter); 
$objReader->setLoadSheetsOnly( $sheetname );

$objPHPExcel = $objReader->load($filename); //memory limit fail
$sheetObj = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet();
var_dump($sheetObj);die();
```

Of course i have `for` loop to read whole file, but it fails even in this test case.

```
Warning: simplexml_load_string() [function.simplexml-load-string]: (null)Entity: line 2: parser error : out of memory error in controllers/PHPExcel/Reader/Excel2007.php on line 652

Warning: simplexml_load_string() [function.simplexml-load-string]: v>579</v></c><c r="B5102" s="2" t="s"><v>688</v></c><c r="C5102" s="2" t="s"><v> in controllers/PHPExcel/Reader/Excel2007.php on line 652

Warning: simplexml_load_string() [function.simplexml-load-string]: ^ in controllers/PHPExcel/Reader/Excel2007.php on line 652
```

I read about Spout, but i can't use it because of php 5.2.17 version in my hosting, also i can't add any extension like php_zip.

Also my chunkReader always read first row of file (`A1, B1, ...`) even start row equal 10 and i dont know what to do with it.

`memory_limit = 256M`

Comment: Perhaps you should show the logic for your chunkReader if it always reads row 1, even when you set start row to 10..... it clearly isn't working as you expect.... though how do you know that it always reads row 1 if it always fails?

Comment: It fails only on large files > ~5000 rows. And my chunkReader is ident to this example https://github.com/cystbear/PHPExcel/blob/master/Documentation/Examples/Reader/exampleReader11.php

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem, I'd try with chunk filter but nothing worked, so I try with setLoadSheetsOnly method before to load the file and it works, of course you will need to review sheet by sheet in your code.

The method setLoadSheetsOnly  can receive a number or the name of the sheet returned by the method getSheetNames ($objXLS->getSheetNames() )

Here's my code

```
$Reader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReaderForFile($file);
$Reader->setReadDataOnly(true); //optional
$Reader->setLoadSheetsOnly($nameOfSheet);
$objXLS = $Reader->load($file);


////// YOUR STUFF
$sheetObj=$objXLS->getSheetByName($nameOfSheet);
$limit=0;
$startFrom = 23; 
$rowCounter=$startFrom;

foreach($sheetObj->getRowIterator($startFrom, $limit) as $row )
{

    echo "<br>Reading row ".$rowCounter."<br>";

    foreach( $row->getCellIterator() as $cell )
    {
        $value = $cell->getCalculatedValue();
        echo $value."  ---  ";
    }
    $rowCounter++;
}
////// YOUR STUFF
```